# Properly discontinuous action on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given a group $H$ with two generators $a$ and $b$, and one relation $abab^{-1}=e,$
I want to show that $H$ acts properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I think that I need to show that for every $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, \exists U$, where $U\owns (x,y)$ is an open set and $h(U)\cap h'(U)=\emptyset,$ for every $h,h'\in H:h\ne h'.$

Any tips on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Well that is part of the difficulty for me. The action is not specified.  I think I have to show that there is such an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $G=\langle a,b \mid abab^{-1}=1 \rangle$ is the fundamental group of a quotient $Q$ of the square $[0,1]^2$; the same thing happens for $\langle a,b \mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}=1 \rangle$ and the torus. And in the same way, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the universal covering of $Q$.

Therefore, $G$ acts properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2/G$ is homeomorphic to $Q$.